# Decimal number in CSV file

Tags: vb.net, csv, tostring, cultureinfo, separator

My application generates CSV file from some objects. These CSV files are used in many countries so I must use correct separator.

To seperate values (cells) in a file I use separator:

```
Dim separator As String = My.Computer.Info.InstalledUICulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator
```

This should be OK. But one column contains decimal numbers so I want to be sure that I use correct decimal separator (must be different than list separator).

I am converting decimal value to a string like this:

```
Dim intValue as Integer = 123456
Dim strValue as String = (intValue / 100).ToString()
```

In my country a list separator is a semicolon and decimal separator is a comma. In this combination it is OK. But I found out that in some country where the list separator is a comma, decimal separator is comma as well. And this is a problem. How I have to convert a decimal number to string if I want to use correct local decimal separator? Thanks!

Comment: The list-separator isn't a country-specific preference: if a semi-colon works for all possible data, I suggest you use it.

Comment: In my country semi-colon is OK. In some other countries a semi-colon is not separator (but comma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I have to convert a decimal number to string if I want to use
>   correct local decimal separator?

By default the current culture's separator is used anyway. But you can use  the overload of `Decimal.ToString` that takes a `CultureInfo`:

```
Dim localizedNumber = (intValue / 100).ToString( CultureInfo.CurrentCulture )
```

If you want to use a different culture:

```
Dim usCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
localizedNumber = (intValue / 100).ToString( usCulture )
```

If you want to know the decimal separator of a given culture:

```
Dim separator As String = usCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator
```

**Edit** So your customers don't want to use tab as separator since they have to specify the delimiter manually. You could either generate a real excel-file, for example by using `EPPlus` which doesn't even need an excel-license or you need to provide another solution.

I have checked it, there are 13 cultures where the decimal-separator is the same as the list-separator (used by excel):

```
Dim conflictCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures).
   Where(Function(c) c.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = c.TextInfo.ListSeparator)
```

So you have to check it manually and then provide a different list-separator. If decimal/list-separator  is comma you can use semicolon as list-separator and vice-versa:

```
Dim argentinaCulture = New CultureInfo("es-AR") ' uses same separator for both
Dim decimalSeparator = argentinaCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator ' comma
Dim listSeparator = argentinaCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator 'comma
If decimalSeparator = listSeparator Then
    listSeparator = If(listSeparator = ",", ";", ",")
End If
```

Comment: OK so if the current culture's separator is used while converting to string, the prolem must be somewhere else. Am I using this code correctly: My.Computer.Info.InstalledUICulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator ? Because in some country both separators are the same (comma).

Comment: @DanielH: why do you assume that both are different at all?  You either have to choose a different decimal separator (f.e. force `.` via `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`) or a list-separator that is less problematic, for example the tab-character `vbTab`.

Comment: My application doesn't open CSV files. Users open it with the Excel. Excel knows local countryInfo on the local PC and uses separators according to it. So I can't choose or force separators. I need to get them from a local system. If someone in China generates a CSV file, anybody in China must be able to open the file with Excel.

Comment: @DanielH: so why don't you generate the csv file with tab-characters as column separator and the correct cultureinfo for your customer's country to get the appropriate decimal separator?

Comment: If I use a tab-character as a column separator, the Excel will not create columns - he is expecting as a column separator comma or semi-colon.

Comment: Thats not true. You can specify the separator in excel.

Comment: Yes but this is not comportable for users. I think that this should be done automatically by application instead of forcing users to do some changes...

Comment: Is it really uncomfortable? 
Maybe you should create a real excel file which is easy even without an excel license for your server, you can for example use `EPPLus`.  But give me a minute, i'll edit my answer to give you another hint.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I naively assumed that column and decimal separators are different everytime. So in this case I have to set separator by myself and user have to change it in the Excel

Comment: I've edited my answer. Btw, here is the step-by-step instruction for your customers: http://superuser.com/questions/291445/how-do-you-change-default-delimiter-in-the-text-import-in-excel